# Target element of a :not function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an function to target links to exclude a style on those links. My links have an ID so I target that id of the a href

```
a:not([id='hopscotch_logo'] { color: red; }
```

I now want to also look for a href children of the id so something like this:

```
a:not([id='hopscotch_logo + a'] { color: red; }
```

Here is some dummy html of the scenario:

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" id="hopscotch_logo" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dont turn me red</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li class="menu-item"><a href="/Tools/Home/ChangePassword.aspx"> I dont want to be red either </a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

I can change the html and/or do it another way, I just need to get the right path to target this child element of my parent id... this is wrong but i imagine its close`a:not([id='hopscotch_logo + a'] {color:red;}`

Comment: Your selectors have some syntax errors.

Comment: Why the `+ a` ? If you wanna look for children shouldn't it be `> a` ?

Comment: @Vivick: Because he described it wrongly. The second a is not a child of the first, as you can tell from the markup. (And besides, an a cannot legally have a child a.)

Comment: This is going to be a very convoluted selector, based on the markup you have.  Based on what you said in your question, since you can change the HTML, I would suggest you just create a different class so you can apply that to the anchors whose style you want to change.

Comment: @scottohara: I'd take two selectors based on a single class name over maintaining two separate class names any day. But that's provided the author knows how to write the selectors in the first place... evidently, that's where Stack Overflow Q&A comes in.

Comment: @BoltClock you would rather maintain ```.dropdown-toggle + .dropdown-menu a { /* insert style */ }```  than ```.dropdown-toggle {} .drop-down-option {}```?  Am I misunderstanding what the question is asking (seems other answers might be too?) but I don't see how the former is preferable.  Also just saw your edit and +1 to that

Comment: @scottohara: Having two class names means you need to maintain them both in the HTML and the CSS. If you're careful you can probably get away with doing so if it means keeping the selectors simplified. Maybe I'm just used to more convoluted selectors.

Comment: @BoltClock I know what having two classes means ;) And this is clearly a difference in theology in how to best maintain CSS. Your method while valid is not reusable across different markup patterns (say i have to create a similar drop down component, but I have to use buttons instead), or the markup changes because the semantics of the component need to be altered. You still have to maintain the HTML and CSS in both of our scenarios, but in mine, I front-load the CSS to be reusable, where as if your pattern changes you need to update both HTML & CSS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142904/discussion-between-scottohara-and-boltclock).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code

```css
a:not(#hopscotch_logo) + a {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="hopscotch_logo" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dont turn me red</a>

<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dont turn me red</a>

<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">turn me red</a>
```

```css
a:not(#hopscotch_logo) + ul a {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" id="hopscotch_logo" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dont turn me red</a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="/Tools/Home/ChangePassword.aspx"> I dont want to be red either </a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">turn me red</a>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="/Tools/Home/ChangePassword.aspx"> I want to be red either </a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Given the HTML the OP shows the `+` selector isn't going to work

Comment: But the second a is not a sibling of the first.

Comment: I don't know what purpose that HTML is trying to serve. You could just as well provide a completely different selector and HTML to go with it, and it would still not answer the question. If you want to answer a different question, find a different question to answer.

Comment: Well yes, that works, but it's not what the OP has, so it's useless

Answer (score 2):

You need two selectors, one for each `a` element.

To reach the second `a` element you first need to go through its `.dropdown-menu` ancestor. Since `.dropdown-menu` is a sibling of the first `a` you can reach the second `a`.

```
a:not(#hopscotch_logo), a:not(#hopscotch_logo) + .dropdown-menu a {
  color: red;
}
```